# When is a companion matrix diagonalizable and what does this say about the associated field extension?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory, companion-matrices

Consider the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -c_0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -c_1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -c_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & -c_{n-2}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & -c_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with rational entries. It is called the *companion matrix* of its charateristic polynomial $p_M$ which equals its minimal polynomial. Assume that $p_M$ is **irreducible** over $\mathbb{Q}$. By considering $p_M$ over the extension $\mathbb{C}\supset\mathbb{Q}$, it splits as
$$
p_m(x)=(x-a_1)^{e_1}\cdots (x-a_k)^{e_k},
$$
but according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), $M$ does not have to be diagonalizable in general.

> - What is an example of an $M$ (such that $p_M$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$) that is not diagonalizable over the complex numbers?
> - As $p_M$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, the matrix $M$ defines an algebraic field extension $L=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p_M)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. How is the property that $M$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ reflected in properties of the field extension?

**Edit** Sorry, I want to assume that $p_M$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, of course.

Comment: A vestige of the originally worded question: Wikipedia does not say the companion matrix of an *irreducible* polynomial needn't be diagonalizable. The word "irreducible" does not appear on the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$A=\Bbb C[M]\cong\frac{\Bbb C[x]}{(p(x))}\cong\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{\Bbb C[x]}{(x-a_i)^{e_i}}.$$

Thus the Jordan blocks $J(\lambda,n)$ of $M$ are $J(a_i,e_i)$ for $i=1,\cdots,k$. A matrix $M$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C\Leftrightarrow$ all its Jordan blocks have size $1$, so $M$ is diagonalizable $\Leftrightarrow p(x)$ is separable.

There was (edit: originally) no hypothesis that $p$ was irreducible, so $\Bbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ needn't be a field.

What we can say is that the maximal ideals of $A$ are in bijection with $p$'s roots, and the $\Bbb C$-algebra $A$ is reduced $\Leftrightarrow M$ is diagonalizable. This relates to the rupture ring $R=\Bbb Q[x]/(p(x))$ via the complexification $A\cong R\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb C$.

Comment: Dear sea turtles, sorry that I did not mention my assumption on the irreducibility of $p_m$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Do I understand you correctly that in this case $M$ is **always** diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ is a perfect field and hence $p_M$ is separable?

Comment: @jeffrey Yes, an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ is separable and the companion matrix of a separable polynomial is diagonalizable in the algebraic closure of its scalars. In fact it even says this in the Wikipedia article you linked ("if $p$ has distinct roots then $C(p)$ is diagonalizable").

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your first question is the polynomial $p(x)=x^2$ with the companion matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ which is not diagonalizable.